# How do I give my friend who I want to beta test my app a copy of iOS 7?

Tags: ios, ios7

I'm a developer and have iOS 7 on my phone now, but I want some beta testers that I know to test my app under iOS 7, and obviously they need it to test my app, so how do I get it to them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add their phone's UUIDs to your portal and the app's provisioning profile. Give them the iOS 7 ISPW file and generate an AdHoc distribution of the app for them.

Comment: "Give them the iOS 7 IPSW file"?  You mean do exactly what Apple tells you **not** to do?  Well, go ahead if it makes you happy but if you get caught have fun never developing for iOS again.

Comment: This violates the NDA!

Comment: Of course it bloody does, if this isn't a violation of the NDA nothing is.

Comment: what is the legal way? test in house? or the tester must participate in the ios developper programm?

Comment: The legal way is to test in house.  Once it becomes public, you can test on a larger scale.  It doesn't make sense to test on a large scale now anyway since iOS 7 is still beta and will change.  Of course IANAL.

Comment: It is legal as long as the device is considered a "development device" registered with Apple's Developer Program (isn't beta testing part of development?).You can see that in the iOS dev center. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: The difference here is that OP wants to also distribute the iOS 7 beta as well.  @KhanhNguyen

Answer (score 2):

**YOU** don't get it to them.  **Apple** gets it to them, if and only if they are registered in the iOS developer program.

Answer (score 1):

According to my knowledge you can send your **tester** the iOS beta version for tests. This is just if this tester is under your developer portal and you are responsible for him to comply with NDA. If the tester would violate the NDA you would be in a serious trouble, so I suggest that if he isn't a part of your organisation (or have some contract between you and him) you should wait .But this is not a legal forum so I suggest you contact Apple about that (I assume they would give you same answer, because it's not logical to provide only developers with the version when all the dev team should have it for tests etc.).

Technically, You must add the test device UDID to your iOS devices at the Developer Portal (then he would be able to use iOS 7 on the test device, I think otherwise could be some activation issues).

To publish an app to that device you must sign it with Ad-Hoc certificate that was created after you added this device (you should mark it).

For sending him the app file in the best way I suggest you use a 3rd party service like TestFlight. That would help you send it very easily and know the status/bugs he finds. If you would also integrate TestFlight SDK you could get a very awesome indication for problems like remote logs etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why not a little kindness, everyone has to start and the system is bewildering.

From the manual
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH35-SW3

Note... there is also something called TestFlight but I haven't really got a hold of it yet.

Quote... it's even clearer in the manual.

Also, use this method if you want to collect device IDs for iOS or Apple TV devices without using Xcode.

To locate a connected device ID using System Information

Connect the device to your Mac.
Open the System Information app located in the /Applications/Utilities folder.
Select USB under Hardware in the left column.
On the right, select the connected device under USB Device Tree.
The device ID, or “Serial Number”, appears below.

Registering Individual Devices
To register a device using Member Center, you need to have the device name and device ID.

To register a single device

In Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles, select Devices.
Under Devices, select All.
Click the Add button (+) in the upper-right corner.
Select Register Device.
Enter a device name and the device ID (UDID).